# Build firefox extension (XPI package) using Java servlets

Tags: java, firefox, servlets, xpi

I am trying to build a xpi file using Java servlet.
If I return the xpi as a zip using the following code in the servlet -

```
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=xpitest.xpi;");
```

Everything works fine with above code. I can save the file to the filesystem and install it.

However, if I try to return the file with the following header and contenttype -

```
response.setContentType("application/x-xpinstall");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","filename=xpitest.xpi;");
```

On the client side, firefox recognizes that the file is an xpi package and shows the Install option. But, when I try to install it, I get this error -
"Not a valid install package - 207"

Can someone suggest what I need to use for setContentType() and setHeader()?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I am using JBoss as the app server.

Answer (score 1):

A traffic sniff from addons.mozilla.org upon clicking on "Add to Firefox" shows that all you need is the Content-Type set to application/x-xpinstall and the right Content-Length. You could try the same. Here are the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2009 04:51:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 05 Nov 2009 15:10:39 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4248
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-xpinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but, since you are returning a zipped .xpi, not an .xpi, I imagine you must use application/zip? if an .xpi is not by nature zipped then indeed a zipped .xpi is not valid by itself. How about sending it uncompressed?

Comment: xpi is just an extension it is a zip files, much like a jar file they are all glorified zip files.

Answer (score 0):

Your second response `Content-Disposition` field is missing an `inline` keyword, may this be a reason?

Also as [Murali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179189/murali) suggested you should set `Content-Length` to an actual value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the content lenght using the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

your servlet should write the document into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, look up its size when done, put that into the `Content-Length` field.

Then send the content via `byteArrayStream.writeTo(response.getOutputStream())`.

-Bipin